# C++ Linking Lapack

Tags: c++, g++

I'm using some code that requires a new version of lapack than the one currently installed on my server.  The system administrator installed lapack on some location: /sysadmin/lapack-3.4.2.

The original command is:

```
g++ -o lapack.os -c -someOptions -IsomeFolders lapack.cpp
```

Now, I'd like to link to the lapack version installed in /sysadmin/lapack-3.4.2.
I tried:

```
g++ -o lapack.os -c -someOptions -IsomeFolders lapack.cpp -L/sysadmin/lapack-3.4.2
```

which didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `-c` option means you want to compile source. You need to pass `-L/sysadmin/lapack-3.4.2` when linking your program.

Answer (score 0):

Please update the question with the error message you are getting.

If you are getting errors during the linking stage I think that's because `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` takes precedence over the paths given with `-L` option.

So your options are:

1. Export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` temporarily excluding the old lapack library path
2. Rename the new lapack library e.g., to newlapack.so and use `-l` option with the new library name

Taking the commands you entered as is, there's no use of the `-L` option if you are going to compile only (`-c`). Are you trying to build an executable from lapack.cpp or create another shared library which you want to link with later?

Answer (score 0):

to compile a shared library with g++ the usual steps are

```
g++ -c -fpic foo.cpp -o foo.o
```

this step just compiles `foo.cpp` into an object, you usually repeat this process for all the source files that you have ( depeding on your codebase and your personal organization of the code in general ), for example you may need to compile another source file to add more to your final library `g++ -c -fpic bar.cpp -o bar.o` .

once you have all the compiled objects you create your final `.so` library with

```
g++ -shared foo.o bar.o -o libsomething.so
```

now to actually use this library ( link it to your executable ) you not only need to add the path of the library to the linker with `-L` but you still need to specify the name of the lib with `-l` like so `-lsomething`, by default the linker adds the *lib* prefix and the *.so* extension.

if you want to launch the application **and** your library it's not in the system's LD path, you can start your application with

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libsomething ./executable
```

remember to specify just the path, not the full address of the single library.